Config error Xdebug with Docker and VSCode?
I am in a Docker environment with separation of PHP and Apache containers.
I'm using PHP 8.2 and Symfony 7.1. I'm trying to add Xdebug in order to solve a SF code problem.
Anyway, despite the numerous tutorials followed, the VSCode debugger does not react despite my breakpoints.
Here is my Docker configuration:
dockerCompose
version: '3.9'
 
networks:
    docker.network:
        driver: bridge
 
services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:8080"
        networks:
            - docker.network
        environment:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: Yes
        volumes:
            - ./db/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
 
    apache:
        image: httpd
        container_name: apache
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            #- "443:443"
        networks:
            - docker.network
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/www
            - ./apache/httpd-vhosts.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
            - ./apache/commun.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/commun.conf
            - ./apache/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
            - ./hosts:/etc/hosts  # Monter le fichier hosts
 
 
    php82:
        build: ./php/php8.2
        container_name: php82
        volumes:
           - ../:/var/www
           - ./php/php.ini:/etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d/30-custom.ini
           - ./php/php.ini:/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/30-custom.ini
           - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/30-custom.ini
           - ./hosts:/etc/hosts  # Monter le fichier hosts
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Paris
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
            - "9004:9004"
        restart: always
        networks:
            - docker.network
        extra_hosts:
            - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
 
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "86:80"
        networks:
            - docker.network
 
    mailer:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        container_name: mailer
        ports:
            - "1025:1025"
            - "8025:8025"
        networks:
            - docker.network

DockerFile
# From
FROM phpdockerio/php:8.2-fpm
 
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 
# Run
RUN apt-get update
 
# Install Nano
RUN apt-get install -y nano
 
RUN apt-get install -y php8.2-mysqli
 
# Install necessary packages for pecl and ODBC
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    php-pear \
    php8.2-dev \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make \
    autoconf \
    libc-dev \
    pkg-config \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    php-xml 
 
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    && pecl install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
    && pecl install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli \
    && pecl install pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo \
    && pecl install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-enable zip \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
 
# Install SQL Server extensions
RUN pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini \
    && pecl install sqlsrv \
    && pecl install pdo_sqlsrv \
    && printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini \
    && printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini \
    && phpenmod -v 8.2 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
    
# Install necessary packages for MS ODBC Driver
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    apt-transport-https \
    gnupg
 
# Add Microsoft's repo for the latest ODBC driver for SQL Server
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
 
# Install the MS ODBC driver for SQL Server
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y \
    msodbcsql17 \
    mssql-tools
 
# Ensure the PHP configuration directory exists
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
 
# Install Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug 
 
# Configure Xdebug
RUN echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/lib/php/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
 
# Créer le répertoire de travail
RUN mkdir -p /var/www
 
# Automatiser les permissions du répertoire
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www

30-custom.ini
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
directorypermissions = "0775"
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
 
max_execution_time = 500
max_input_time = 500
memory_limit = 256M
 
; zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20220829/xdebug.so
; xdebug.mode=debug
; xdebug.start_with_request=yes
; xdebug.client_host=172.0.0.1
; xdebug.client_port=9004
 
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20220829/xdebug.so
; ; zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.idekey=XDEBUG_SESSION_START
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=/dev/stdout
xdebug.log_level=0
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal

I did a php_info() where I have the instantiation of Xdebug:

I then configured my VSCode with the PHP debug extension, and the debugger settings. Here is my lunch.json file:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I tested either with POSTMAN or by directly calling the URL http://datalookup.local/index.php/lookup/liste-marques
For browsers, I added the Xdebug helper extension, which is activated. Unfortunately, absolutely nothing happens in VSCode.
I tested with another port 9004, which I opened on the docker container, but nothing.
I don't really know where to turn anymore. Can you help me?
Do you need additional information?
I tested with different ports, I tested with different keys, and changing networks. I followed various tutorials including that of grafikart.

text
text


"I did a php_info() where I have the instantiation of Xdebug:" You have Xdebug 3. I suggest you use xdebug_info() instead -- post the WHOLE output. It will show the current/live config values. Make sure to do this for the same environment where  you are trying to debug (I mean -- a CLI or a web page debug).

"Here is my lunch.json file:" I'm not using VSCode for PHP (only did some tests there), but I would remove this "hostname": "127.0.0.1",  line -- at least try without this line. On some OS / setups this binding for a specific address does not work properly / causes some issues.

"I tested with another port 9004, which I opened on the docker container, but nothing." That's obviously WRONG. You do not need to open anything in containers for Xdebug (remove these ports:             - "9000:9000"             - "9004:9004"). Simply because it's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. If you have those ports used by Docker, then VSCode will not be able to listen on them...

Last suggestion: Enable Xdebug logging (also get rid of xdebug.log_level=0), try to debug and see what the log has to tell. It will show where Xdebug tries to connect to (if at all) and what the response is.

For xdebug_info() I put it in a file at the root of my www. I tried to put it at the root of my project but it is a Symfony and it does not recognize this method, no matter where I put it, so it is difficult to be as close as possible to my call of api that I want to test.
I then ran various tests without the "hostname" parameter, in my lunch.json file, and what seems to work best is this "hostname": "localhost".
I tested by removing "xdebug.log_level=0", but that didn't change anything, or by putting "xdebug.log_level=10", but I have no improvement.

I then tried different ports. The problem is that my application runs with docker on port 9000. IF I don't put it, nothing works, so I have to have at least this one.
I nevertheless carried out tests by declaring port 9003 in php.ini and in lunch.json, but this time I got an error in the return from xdebug_info(). So I tried to declare it in the open ports of my container via docker_compose. But I still have the same error.

[Step Debug] Creating socket for '172.19.0.1:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[Step Debug] Could not connect to client host discovered through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[Step Debug] Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.19.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

If I stay with port 9000 configured everywhere, the return from xdebug_info() tells me that everything is good. And when I try to make a call, I look at the xdebug logs and I see this.
Development Helpers ✔ enabled
Step Debugger ✔ enabled
Diagnostic Log
No messages
Debugger Active
Connected Client 172.19.0.1:9000

[7] Log opened at 2024-08-19 13:38:37.222478
[7] [Config] INFO: Control socket set up succesfully: '@xdebug-ctrl.7'
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking for client discovery headers: 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,REMOTE_ADDR'.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 172.19.0.1:9000.
[7] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.19.0.1:9000 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header).

[7] [Step Debug] -> XdebugDerick Rethanshttps://xdebug.orgCopyright (c) 2002-2024 by Derick Rethans

[7] [Step Debug] -> 
[7] [Step Debug] WARN: The debugging client closed the connection on socket 9: Broken pipe (error: 32).
[7] Log closed at 2024-08-19 13:38:46.040713


If you are using Docker .. then it should really be trying to connect to host.docker.internal:900x where 900x is the Xdebug port where the VSCode is listening to (and that port should NOT be forwarded/used by Docker). 2) If it tries to connect to some another IP -- maybe better to remove the xdebug.discover_client_host=true line. That's as much as I can say here.


Thx LazyOne for your help

I finally found it.
I removed the port declaration in the dockerFile and the php.ini.
And I set the default port in lunch.json to be 9003, and for my docker-compose I only left the port for my code to be 9000.
Then I had a problem with a breakpoint that wasn't recognized or caught, so I changed the pathMappings to target not the root of my dev folder, but my project directly.
lunch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
     {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/api-global": "c:/Users/gnicolle/Sites/api-global"
        }
     }
  ]
}

30-custom.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log_level=10
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal

